# Truffle Compile Fails with Error " Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function definition"

Tags: truffle, nodejs, compilation, truffle-compile

When running `truffle compile` in the root directory of my project I get the following error:

```
ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function definition.
 --> /C/Users/connova/Documents/carebuds-finance/CareBuds-Finance/contracts/$420Donations.sol:1:1:
  |
1 | ﻿pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
  | ^

,ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function definition.
 --> /C/Users/connova/Documents/carebuds-finance/CareBuds-Finance/contracts/BudsDonation.sol:1:1:
  |
1 | ﻿pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
  | ^
```

I have several contracts in my  project but the two I'm getting this error for are below:

$420Donations.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GNU General Public License v3.0

/**
 * @dev Interface of the ERC20 standard as defined in the EIP.
 */
interface IERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
     */
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
     * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
     * zero by default.
     *
     * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
     * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
     * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
     * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
     * desired value afterwards:
     * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `sender` to `recipient` using the
     * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
     * another (`to`).
     *
     * Note that `value` may be zero.
     */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
     * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
     */
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract $420Donations {

    address $420;
    address payable goodBudsWallet;
    address payable smokeOutWallet;
    
    uint initialTime;
    
    bool[] monthlyDonationStatus; //log of donation status of each month since initialTime

    event Deposit (address sender, uint amount, uint balance, uint time);
    event Donation (address wallet, uint amount, uint balance, uint time); 
    
    constructor (address $420Address, address goodBudsWalletAddress, address smokeOutWalletAddress) {
        
        require($420Address != address(0));
        require(goodBudsWalletAddress != address(0));
        require(smokeOutWalletAddress != address(0));
    
        //setting initialTime as time of contract creation
        initialTime = block.timestamp;
        $420 = $420Address;
        goodBudsWallet = payable(goodBudsWalletAddress);
        smokeOutWallet = payable(smokeOutWalletAddress);
    }
    
    //a function that allows people to donate to this contract
    //this will be called to deposit the 6.9% of the $420 total supply
    function deposit(address token, uint amount) public payable {
        
        require(token == $420, "Sorry, those tokens aren't accepted here");
        require(IERC20($420).balanceOf(msg.sender) > amount, "You're balance is insufficient");
        
        IERC20($420).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        
        uint newBalance = IERC20($420).balanceOf(address(this)); 
        
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, amount, newBalance, block.timestamp);
    }

    function donate() public {
            
        uint timeSinceInitialTime = block.timestamp - initialTime;
        uint currentMonth = timeSinceInitialTime/(30 days + (1 days)/2);
        
        require(monthlyDonationStatus[currentMonth] == false, "This month's donation has already completed");
        
        IERC20($420).transferFrom(address(this), goodBudsWallet, 4200);
        IERC20($420).transferFrom(address(this), smokeOutWallet, 4200);
        
        monthlyDonationStatus[currentMonth] = true;
        
        uint newBalance = IERC20($420).balanceOf(address(this)); 
        
        emit Donation(goodBudsWallet, 4200, newBalance, block.timestamp);
        emit Donation(smokeOutWallet, 4200, newBalance, block.timestamp);
    }
}
```

BudsDonations.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GNU General Public License v3.0

/**
 * @dev Interface of the ERC20 standard as defined in the EIP.
 */
interface IERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
     */
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
     * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
     * zero by default.
     *
     * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
     * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
     * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
     * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
     * desired value afterwards:
     * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `sender` to `recipient` using the
     * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
     * another (`to`).
     *
     * Note that `value` may be zero.
     */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
     * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
     */
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract BudsDonations {

    address Buds;
    address payable goodBudsWallet;
    address payable smokeOutWallet;
    
    uint initialTime;
    
    bool[] monthlyDonationStatus; //log of donation status of each month since initialTime

    event Deposit (address sender, uint amount, uint balance, uint time);
    event Donation (address wallet, uint amount, uint balance, uint time); 
    
    constructor (address budsAddress, address goodBudsWalletAddress, address smokeOutWalletAddress) {

        require(budsAddress != address(0));
        require(goodBudsWalletAddress != address(0));
        require(smokeOutWalletAddress != address(0));
    
        //setting initialTime as time of contract creation
        initialTime = block.timestamp;
        Buds = budsAddress;
        goodBudsWallet = payable(goodBudsWalletAddress);
        smokeOutWallet = payable(smokeOutWalletAddress);
    }
    
    //a function that allows people to deposit to this contract
    function deposit(address token, uint amount) public payable {
        
        require(token == Buds, "Sorry, those tokens aren't accepted here");
        require(IERC20(Buds).balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount, "You're balance is insufficient");
        
        IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        
        uint newBalance = IERC20(Buds).balanceOf(address(this)); 
        
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, amount, newBalance, block.timestamp);
    }

    function donate() public {
            
        uint timeSinceInitialTime = block.timestamp - initialTime;
        uint currentMonth = timeSinceInitialTime/(30 days + (1 days)/2);
        
        require(monthlyDonationStatus[currentMonth] == false, "This month's donation has already completed");
        
        IERC20(Buds).transferFrom(address(this), goodBudsWallet, 4200);
        IERC20(Buds).transferFrom(address(this), smokeOutWallet, 4200);
        
        monthlyDonationStatus[currentMonth] = true;
        
        uint newBalance = IERC20(Buds).balanceOf(address(this)); 
        
        emit Donation(goodBudsWallet, 4200, newBalance, block.timestamp);
        emit Donation(smokeOutWallet, 4200, newBalance, block.timestamp);
    }
}
```

This is my output for truffle version

```
Truffle v5.4.0 (core: 5.4.0)
Solidity - ^0.8.0 (solc-js)
Node v14.17.3
Web3.js v1.4.0
```

Please let me know  you're help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I tried the contract with the same settings replacing node with v10.24 and it compiled without issues.

Comment: You downgraded node to get it to work? Shouldn't we use the latest version?

Comment: I had v10 installed, but trying again with node v14.15.4, truffle v5.4, solc 0.8.6 it compiled `$420Donations.sol` without issues. I don't know what can be wrong, the code seems fine, try reinstalling node, truffle, using another directory, computer, vm.

Comment: Well, my directory had many contracts, each of them compiling correctly in the remix IDE. This error I'm mentioning only occurs when I try to compile all the contracts in the directory at once. However, if I delete all the secondary contracts (that I don't really need in the same repo) then the single contract I have compiles perfectly. Once I have all my contracts in a single directory and try to compile that's when the error happens...

Answer (score 0):

Check if your .sol file is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM.

Otherwise, convert to UTF-8.

I used Notepad++ to do that.

Encoding > Convert to UTF-8